# How can I convert this SQL query to Linq with C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Since I am new to Linq so not able to convert this SQL query to Linq I am pasting my code that I have already tried, it gives null records.

Thanks in advance.

This is my Linq C# Statements that I have tried:

```
from ts in Db.Tasks

join prt in Db.ProjectTasks on ts.Id equals prt.TaskId into PojTsk
from t1 in PojTsk 

join TL in Db.Timeline on ts.Id equals TL.TypeId into Tmln
from t2 in Tmln

join DUR in Db.Duration on ts.Id equals DUR.TypeId into Dur
from t3 in Tmln

where t1.ProjectId == ProjectId 
&& t2.Type == (int)Provider.EntityType.TASK 
&& t3.Type == (int)Provider.EntityType.TASK
select ts
```

This is my SQL query that I am trying to convert to Linq with C#:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('T', R1.Id)  as Id, 
    R1.Name, R1.Description, R1.Priority, 
    R1.Stage, R1.Status, R1.CreatorId, 
    R2.ProjectId, R3.StartDate, R3.EndDate, 
    R3.LatestEndDate, R3.LatestStartDate, 
    R3.EarliestStartDate, R3.ActualStart, R3.ActualEnd, 
    R3.RemTime, R3.ReshowDate, R3.RemTime, R3.Completed, 
    R4.ActualDuration, R4.ActualDurationPlanned      
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM [ProjectManagement].[dbo].[Tasks] AS TS) AS R1
JOIN
    (SELECT * 
     FROM [ProjectManagement].[dbo].[ProjectTasks]) AS R2 ON R1.Id = R2.TaskId
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM [ProjectManagement].[dbo].[Timelines] 
     WHERE Type = 3) AS R3 ON R1.Id = R3.TypeId
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM [ProjectManagement].[dbo].[Durations] 
     WHERE Type = 3) AS R4 ON R1.Id = R4.TypeId
WHERE
    ProjectId = 1
```

[My sql query result in SQL Server Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2xIm.png)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356439/left-join-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: there is no syntax of select * from.

Comment: Did you tried this one? http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: @Mahesh Malpani, how can you say that "there is no syntax of select * from" I have tested this query on my SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: You now asking about specific library. Not sure about that but you can use entity framework and .net linq instead of that

Comment: Those who have down voted my question do they answer my question? :-)

Comment: What is `Db`? In other words, what type of LINQ are you using? Further, show the class model. This is all so much easier with navigation properties. You probably don't need one single LINQ join statement.

Answer (score 0):

Even still unable to determine which query should be executed first, I had figured out query execution steps:

> (1) Inner join Tasks table with ProjectTasks table where ProjectId = 1,
>
> (2) Left join (1) to Timelines table where Type = 3,
>
> (3) Left join (2) to Durations table where Type = 3.

My nearest approach on given SQL query with LINQ (I have neither test into LINQPad nor directly to VS yet):

```
// first inner join
var query = (from R1 in Tasks
join R2 in ProjectTasks on R1.Id equals R2.TaskId into Group1

// second left join
from T1 in Group1.DefaultIfEmpty() 
join R3 in (from t in Timelines where t.Type == 3 select t) on T1.Id equals R3.TypeId into Group2

// third left join
from T2 in Group2.DefaultIfEmpty()
join R4 in (from d in Durations where d.Type == 3 select d) on T2.Id equals R4.TypeId

// still not sure to determine where condition here...
where T2.ProjectId == 1 // join result condition

select new {
    Id = T1.Id.ToString().Concat("T"), // assume Tasks.Id is an int identity column converted to String value
    Name = T1.Name,
    Description = T1.Description,
    Priority = T1.Priority,
    Stage = T1.Stage,
    Status = T1.Status,
    CreatorId = T1.CreatorId,
    ProjectId = T1.ProjectId,
    StartDate = T2.StartDate,
    EndDate = T2.EndDate,
    LatestEndDate = T2.LatestEndDate,
    EarliestStartDate = T2.EarliestStartDate,
    ActualStart = T2.ActualStart,
    ActualEnd = T2.ActualEnd,
    RemTime = T2.RemTime,
    ReshowDate = T2.ReshowDate,
    Completed = T2.Completed,
    ActualDuration = R4.ActualDuration,
    ActualDurationPlanned = R4.ActualDurationPlanned
}).ToList();
```

CMIIW.

Comment: Thanks for your kind replay, but result is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from ts  in Db.Tasks
join prt in Db.ProjectTasks on ts.Id equals prt.TaskId
from tl  in Db.Timeline.Where(x => (x.TypeId == ts.Id)
                                && (x.Type == (int)Provider.EntityType.TASK))
                       .DefaultIfEmpty()
from dur in Db.Duration.Where(x => (x.TypeId == ts.Id)
                                && (x.Type == (int)Provider.EntityType.TASK))
                       .DefaultIfEmpty()

where  (prt.ProjectId == ProjectId)

select new {
    Id = "T" + ts.Id,
    ts.Name,
    ts.Description,
    //...

    prt.ProjectId,

    tl.StartDate,
    tl.EndDate,
    tl.LatestEndDate,
    //...

    dur.ActualDuration,
    dur.ActualDurationPlanned
}
```

`from x in y.DefaultIfEmpty()` is a simple way to create a `LEFT JOIN`.

**EDIT:** Changed `.Where()` in left joins.

Comment: Result is null still.

Comment: I tried your Linq and also changed where condition but no luck   (from ts in Db.Tasks
                                 join prt in Db.ProjectTasks on ts.Id equals prt.TaskId
                                 from tl in Db.Timeline.Where(x => x.TypeId == ts.Id && x.Type == 3)
                                 from dur in Db.Duration.Where(x => x.TypeId == ts.Id && x.Type == 3)
                                 where (prt.ProjectId == ProjectId)</code>

Comment: See this answer to log the SQL generated by EF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20751723/1869660  Then it's easier to see what's wrong. (Note: I updated my answer with you corrected where conditions)

Comment: Ok, but find the SQL that EF generates (see the link in my comment). Then it will be easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10871686 I am getting this query. by loging, can u please help, I think it's inner join not left join

Comment: You're right, those are inner joins. If you're using `.DefaultIfEmpty()`, that's strange. See this similar question, which have answers with a few different syntaxes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748425/how-to-use-left-join-in-entity-framework-query